# Change NumericPagerField ButtonCount property at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, runtime, datapager

I implement paging for ListView in ASP.NET with DataPager and ObjectDataSource, it have worked really well for years but now the problem appears.

We currently set the PageSize at 15, and the ButtonCount = 5. For a million rows we have over 66k pages. The problem is: the width of the DataPager control is limited to a specific number and it's OK in the first block (1,2,3...) but when we move to the last block (66000, 660001, 66002,...) the paging control is overflowed the container.

We came to a solution that calculate the pagenumber based on the StartRowIndex and the PageSize of the DataPager control and then re-set the ButtonCount value by using

```
(DataPager.Fields[<NumericPagerFieldIndex>] as NumericPagerField).ButtonCount = x
```

Then, strange things happen: When we move to the last page (66667), click on the 66666, we all think that it'll change the page number to 66666 but no, instead of 66666, 66664 is selected.

We don't know why and have google around, also read the code of DataPager but still found nothing.

Any helps would be appreciated!